# how to implement a Label on the fiori header bar for specific app

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

Experts, I need a label on my Fiori header bar for a specific app.
I mean not for all apps.

I have added the following lines of code in my app.

```
var oRendererExtensions = jQuery.sap.getObject("sap.ushell.renderers.fiori2.RendererExtensions");

oRendererExtensions.setHeaderTitle(“Some Title”);
```

But the issue is once I open my app title is coming for me but it's not disappearing for others apps too.
Please help on this.

Comment: would it help if you set title to empty string on the component's destruction of your app?

Comment: Can you please show a screenshot how your label in the header looks like?
In which file did you add your coding? controller.js?
Can you add the label also in the xml view?
Maybe the following links with samples for title and header might help:
[sample title](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.Title/preview) & 

[Sample: List - Header & Info Toolbar](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.ListToolbar/preview) In the very top right on these pages, you can show the source code for these samples.